# Oauth2-server-laravel always ask to approve/deny after login

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, oauth-2.0

I am newbie in Oauth2 and laravel. I am trying to implement Authorization Server in laravel with authorization code grant. I followed all implementation instruction mentioned in https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel.

Every thing is working fine except user need to approve/deny on each login to get access code. I want to show authorization-form only once when user first time ask for authorization and not every time, similar to how Oauth2 is implemented in google.

How can I do it, any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have implemented a solution for your issue in one of my work, here is the sample code, hope that help:

```
Route::get('/oauth/authorize', array('before' => 'check-authorization-params|auth', function() {
    // get the data from the check-authorization-params filter
    $params            = Session::get('authorize-params');
    // get the user id
    $params['user_id'] = Auth::user()->id;

    if ($params['approval_prompt'] != 'force')
    {
        $session = DB::table('oauth_sessions')->where('client_id', '=', $params['client_id'])
                ->where('owner_type', '=', 'user')
                ->where('owner_id', '=', $params['user_id'])
                ->first();
        if ($session)
        {
            $code = AuthorizationServer::newAuthorizeRequest('user', $params['user_id'], $params);
            Session::forget('authorize-params');
            return Redirect::to(AuthorizationServer::makeRedirectWithCode($code, $params));
        }
    }

    // display the authorization form
    return View::make('authorization-form', array('params' => $params));
}));
```

If the `approval_prompt` is not set to `force`, then I will check whether if there are any sessions belong to this user and show the authorization form only if there is no saved sessions.

**Notice:** This code is for the 1.0 version of the package, if you're using another version, there may be some different things.

Comment: I am using 3.0 Oauth2 version. With some modification it works on my case. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is modification of Hieu Le answer for Laravel 5.1 and lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel with league/oauth2-server 4.1.2

```
Route::get('/oauth/authorize', ['as' => 'oauth.authorize.get','middleware' => ['check-authorization-params', 'auth'], function() {
    // display a form where the user can authorize the client to access it's data
    $authParams = Authorizer::getAuthCodeRequestParams();
    $authParams['client_id'] = $authParams['client']->getId();
    $formParams = array_except($authParams,'client');

    $authParams['user_id'] = Auth::user()->id;

    if (array_get($authParams, 'approval_prompt', null) != 'force')
    {
        $session = DB::table('oauth_sessions')->where('client_id', '=', $authParams['client_id'])
            ->where('owner_type', '=', 'user')
            ->where('owner_id', '=', $authParams['user_id'])
            ->first();
        if ($session)
        {
            $redirectUri = Authorizer::issueAuthCode('user', $authParams['user_id'], $authParams);
            return Redirect::to($redirectUri);
        }
    }

    return View::make('oauth.authorization-form', ['params'=>$formParams,'client'=>$authParams['client']]);
}]);
```